# How to save leaflet vector map to an image

Tags: javascript, canvas, printing, leaflet, maps

I seem unable to save a leaflet map with vectors to an image, Whatever I try I always get an empty canvas/image. The only thing that is saved in the image are the map controls, the markers and other images

What i have tried so far:

- regular canvas.dataToUrl()
- Leaflet.print

I'm now trying html2canvas and what I found is that if I select the div wrapping the map I get an empty image/canvas. But at some point I let the entire body be converted to canvas and sometimes the map tiles would appear in the canvas/image but that's not really reliable.

The code I use so far

```
setTimeout(function() {
let html2canvasConfiguration = {
    useCORS: true,
    allowTaint: true,
    backgroundColor: null,
    logging: true,
    imageTimeout: 0,
};

let elementToCapture = $body.find(".similar-properties")[0];
console.log(elementToCapture);
html2canvas(elementToCapture, html2canvasConfiguration).then(function (canvas) {
    //let canvasData = canvas.toDataURL();
    //console.log(canvasData);
    $("body").prepend(canvas);
});
},4000);
```

I also tried several other recommended print plugins for leaflet but all seem to work best with image tiles and not vector tiles

So my question is if this is actually possible to reliably generate an image from a leaflet vector map? are there alternative ways to approach this? preferably a way without having to setup an entire server.

ps: I did read about Mapfish but not sure if this is still maintained

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#printexport

Comment: like I mentioned... I tried those